# Install PHPUNIT with Composer

Tags: php, windows, symfony, phpunit, wamp

I have project on Symfony 2 and i would like use PHPUNIT on Windows 7.

```
On githut phpunit is:

Composer

Simply add a dependency on phpunit/phpunit to your project's composer.json file if you use Composer to manage the dependencies of your project. Here is a minimal example of a composer.json file that just defines a development-time dependency on PHPUnit 3.7:

{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
    }
}
For a system-wide installation via Composer, you can run:

composer global require 'phpunit/phpunit=3.7.*'
Make sure you have ~/.composer/vendor/bin/ in your path.
```

First i use system-wide installation but i dont know when this installed. 
Next i add to my composer.json require-dev.
This installed phpunit in C:/wamp/www/myproject/vendor/symfony. Next i try commands:

```
 composer install --dev
```

And i can't use phpunit. In cmd.exe i enter "phpunit" and i have error:

```
'phpunit' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file
```

How can i use phpunit? I have Windows 7, Wamp server and php 5.4.12.

Answer (score 14):

When you install PHP-Unit in windows via composer, the global installation will create files in

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Composer
```

To execute `phpunit` easily via command line you need to add path of `phpunit.bat` file in windows Environment Variables. For this:

> 1. Right click `My Computer`
> 2. Go to `Properties -> Advance system settings` and
> 3. Click `Environment variables` from the `Advance` tab.

Now add `C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin` to the windows `PATH`.

You can now run the phpunit from command. Note that you may need to restart your command prompt for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Also if you are using the terminal via an IDE such as PhpStorm you will need to close and reopen it for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 13):

The bin file of packages are put in the configured bin directory. By default, this is `vendor/bin` and when you use the symfony standard edition, this is the `bin` folder.

To execute this bin file, run `./bin/phpunit` (or `./vendor/bin/phpunit` when not using the Symfony Standard Edition)

Windows users have to put this in double quotes: `"bin/phpunit"` (or `"vendor/bin/phpunit"`)

Comment: I have phpunit in folder C:/wamp/www/myproject/vendor/phpunit. So i go to C:/wamp/www/myproject and put "vendor/phpunit" and i have error '"vendor/phpunit"' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file

Comment: Yes, but you need to execute a phpunit file, which is in vendor/bin or in bin

Answer (score 6):

```
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit ^9
```

The above example assumes, composer is already on your $PATH variable.

You composer.json should look similar to;

```
{
  "name": "vendor_name/package_name",
  "description": "This project is for practicing writing php unit tests",
  "minimum-stability": "stable",
  "license": "proprietary",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Umair Anwar",
      "email": "umair.anwar@gmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "src/"
    ]
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9",
    "phpunit/dbunit": "^4.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Easiest way to install phpunit via composer is to run from project root.

```
$ composer require phpunit/phpunit
```

What this would do is, it will create a phpunit folder inside vendor/bin 
and you can run unit tests like this..

```
$ ./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Answer (score 2):

**Too simple operation on Windows with composer and works for me following way:**

> `Install composer`
>   https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows Go to
>   your symphony folder e.g C:\wamp64\www\symfony\UserManagement where is
>   composer.json and run this command.
>   **Should be register with global to not have issue $phpunit bash: phpunit: command not found**

```
//old version is 5.7 new 6.4 or put newest version.
composer global require --dev phpunit/phpunit ^5.7
```

Answer (score 1):

I remember futzing around with the composer dependency stuff for phpunit and never could get it to work.

Instead, from your git bash shell:

```
mkdir ~/bin
cd ~/bin
curl https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar > phpunit
chmod +x phpunit
```

exit out of bash and then start a new bash session.

And you should be good to go.  You can echo $PATH to verify you have a path to ~/bin but one seems to added by default.

https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar

Answer (score 0):

I also came across the same issue and find out the solution by following steps

To run PHPUnit in Windows 7 under WAMP installation

1. Composer Install

   {
       "require-dev": {
           "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
       }
   }
2. Simply Set Environment Variable
   The php unit will be install in a vendor dir in vendor/bin

   Path : C:\wamp\www\myproject\vendor\bin;
3. Open a new Command Prompt 
   C:\Users\guny >phpunit  --version
   PHPUnit 3.7.30 by Sebastain Bergmann