# PHPUnit switching from PEAR to Composer

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php, pear

Now I installed Composer on my system (system wide) (I'm currently on Windows).
I don't wanna use the PHPUnit instace I installed before using PEAR. I want to use the new version of PHPUnit which I now installed via Composer into my project. My first step was to uninstall the `PEAR:phpunit` and `PEAR:phpunit2` package. But when I now type phpunit, I get

```
$ phpunit
bash.exe": /c/xampp/php/phpunit: No such file or directory
```

I then tried `type phpunit` to look up the alias.
This resulted in `phpunit is hashed (/c/xampp/php/phpunit)`.

How would I be able to fully switch to my working PHPUnit instance in my project directory which I installed using Composer (remove this hashed alias?)?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: [Official manual to remove PEAR PHPUnit](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/End-of-Life-for-PEAR-Installation-Method#removing-a-pear-installed-phpunit-environment) might help. Also, try I'd try only installing PHPUnit via composer . You might not need to remove PEAR at all.

Comment: I don't want to remove PEAR at all. But I now was able to overwrite the old alias set by PEAR for PHPUnit with a new one pointing to my PHPUnit ibstalled using Composer.

Comment: Check your directory bin

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install PHPUNIT with Composer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18688059/install-phpunit-with-composer)